# Installing iOS SDK 4.1 on xcode 3.2.5

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk

I've read through a lot of posts and couldn't really figure out the answer to this question. So I apologize if I duplicating it here.

I have installed xcode 3.2.5 to my machine and it comes with SDK 4.2. My iPhone is on 4.1 and I am not planning to move it to 4.2 just yet. Problem is that I can't use this phone for testing. Since the only SDK that I have installed is 4.2, when I try to run debug with my iPhone, I get this message:

**Can't install application**

*The info.plist for application at /blabla/app.app specifies a minimum OS of 4.2, which is too high to be installed on this device.*

So, I got to Targets -> Get Info and I see that it is indeed targeting 4.2 (but that is the only option available - since I don't have the other SDK's installed).

So, the question is: how to I keep xcode 3.2.5, but install SDK 4.1 in addition to 4.2?

Answer (score 8):

It took a while to figure this out. 
I couldn't see 'iOS Deployment Target' on the info.plist either. Here's what I did.

a) Project -> Edit Project Settings 
b) go to 'deployment' section 
c) Change 
      'Targeted Device Family' = iPhone/iPad 
      'iOS Deployment Target = 'iOS 4.1'

Comment: iOS Deployment Target is the minimum iOS version that can be supported by the specified application. Therefore, if you set it as iOS 4.1, you can run the application on 4.1 or upper iOS-vernon device

Answer (score 3):

Open up your `info.plist` in your project. There is a place where you can define for iOS 4.1.

Comment: @Luis rather than saying "than you" just click on the "accept" icon. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just open the previous SDK dmg, then go to Packages, and install the SDK 4.1 package.

More info : [Install sdk 2.0 to 3.1 for xcode 3.2](http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/)

Note : the "Packages" directory is not visible in the dmg since xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final. Just use the Terminal (or finder "Go to folder") to open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Packages".

Edit : the xcode4.1 for Snow Leopard create an app called "Install Xcode.app". The packages directory is inside the app package.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to find a copy of Xcode 3.2.4, with iOS 4.1, and install it in a separate directory. When you install, take the dropdown that's set to Developer and switch it to `DevOld`, or something similar. As there's no way to install new SDKs in the new version of Xcode, keeping multiple versions is the best you can do.

If you simply want to be able to run your app in 4.1, not necessarily develop in it, go into your target's settings, and under the build tab, set the `iOS Deployment Target` key to 4.1 or below.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:
In the BUILD section of the Project info click on Show and change its value from Setting defined at this level to All Settings.

In the updated list of settings you will surely locate the desired one.

Good Luck!